# Searching a common substring presence

Tags: algorithms

Some time ago during an interview for software developer position I was asked the following task:

Supposing we have two immense texts (like till million of characters each) and we are asked whether they both do contain the occurrence of the same sub-string of exactly 50 characters long. The answer we need to give should be either *yes* or *no*.

I was told that the solution to this task includes following steps:

1. Presenting the text as a numeric sequence, i.e. each letter corresponds to the particular number. Then we do reflect this all on Cartesian x-y coordinates, so *x* is our letter numeric value, and *y* it's position in the text. I'm ok with that.
2. Then to respond the initial question we are analyzing the functions that do result from above, i.e. according to the interviewer we are to analyze its *maximums* and *minimums*.

My question is could someone explain the idea of the algorithm above. Probably give some indices, examples so I could dig out myself.

Comment: Are there any heuristic algorithms of resolving such an algorithmic task?